# How to draw a single dot in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Is it possible to draw a single dot in iOS? I've gone this way which I think is not right:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 30 ,y: 50 ), radius: CGFloat(1), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
```

Is it ok to draw shapes with loops?

Answer (score 2):

why can't you take a one view and give a background color black and give Width and height same sizes and give cornerradius height/2

Comment: Because i want too many dots, and i dont know their position before run time